# How to add jquery in GWT page

Tags: gwt

I have a GWT Application , I need to add Jquery in my GWT 
as i wish to have HighCharts in GWT and for that i have to have Jquery coz HighCharts need them for that purpose I need to have Jquery in my Page
How to add Jquery in my GWT Page ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably use [gwtQuery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) instead. It's a port of jQuery written for GWT.

If you really think you need to use jQuery, download the js from their site, add it to your war directory, and reference it in your entry point's HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery in gwt application easily using native method.
you have to add js files in html page and than create class that contain only JSNI methods and jsobject and you can easily use jquery in your gwt application

you can easily learn from http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-ui/